# Identity morphism requirement in categories

Tags: category-theory

In order to verify a category, you need to show that the class of morphisms respect associativity and contains an identity morphism.

I'm looking for a class of morphisms that doesn't contain an identity morphism.

It seems that you could always define a map $x \mapsto x$. But then why require it to be an axiom for categories?

Comment: Consider the following "category without identities": there is a unique object: $\Bbb{Z}$. The class of morphisms is the set of non-negative functions $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$. Composition is well defined, but there is no identity. In particular this is not a category.

Comment: @Crostul What about the identity $x \mapsto x$, which is a non-negative function?

Comment: $x \mapsto x$ is not a nonnegative function since it maps every negative number to negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you're asking for an example of a [semicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory) that isn't a category.

Recall that every monoid $M$ becomes a category $\mathbb{B}M$ as follows:

- There's precisely one object, denoted $*$
- A morphism $* \rightarrow *$ is just an element of $M$.
- $\mathrm{id}_*$ is $1_M$.
- Composition of morphisms is given by multiplying elements of $M$.

The same goes for every semigroup $S$, except that $\mathbb{B}S$ is in general only a semicategory. For a concrete example: let $S = (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},+)$. Then $\mathbb{B}S$ is a semicategory that fails to be a category.

Comment: A morphism needn't be an element of $M$, right? In the case of semigroups, we can, for instance, define the morphisms as semigroup homomorphisms. The identity is then given by the identity homomorphism. We then have the category of semigroups.

Comment: @MusséRedi, if I've understood you correctly, that's exactly right.